# Dropown menu open/close

Tags: jquery, wordpress, bootstrap-5

I use navbar menu from Bootstrap5.
My dropdown doesn't open or close

i add a jquery function and the drowpdown works only to open but not top close

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function (event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');
});
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function (event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu.show').removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Both of your click handler fire for every click.  Make just one event handler.  Check `hasClass('show')` against the element, to determine what it needs to do.  Or just `$('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the addClass to a toggleClass and remove the second click detection:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function (event) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use jQuery in Bootstrap 5. Just make sure you're using the appropriate `data-bs-` attribues on the dropdown toggler..

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
 </li>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/EkDcCXr2YS)